# Function module "SUBST_GET_INSTNO" : Since when does it perform authority-check?

Tags: authorization, abap, sap-basis

We have a customer, running on the same release, as we (7.40).
However, the mentioned function module is different in the customer's system compared to ours.
This is the screenshot of the customer's module, where the different sections are yellow highlighted. Since which SP these lines are added ?

[image]

Comment: Easiest way to find this info is probably to search OSS for notes related to this FM.

Comment: This belongs to Software Component SAP_BASIS. My version is Release 740 SP-Level 0006 and there is no such an authority check there.

Comment: The same for SAP_BASIS 711 0013. No authority check there either.

Comment: THX. Might be, the customer installs basis-sp's more frequently then others. Was a strange experience, when our software suddenly did not create proxy-code in .net, after this check failed, and I thought, my installation of our code-generator was buggy, but not. The check failed.

Comment: @BryanCain Peformed the search, no results related to SAP notes there.

Comment: @icbytes Do you have a possibility to check the SP-level of SAP_BASIS on the system with the authority check in this FM?

Comment: The customer has SAP_BASIS release 740. SP 11. Our systems have release 740, SP 9. There it is. 10 or 11 might have implemented this.
So easy to spot. Not even worth asking. Should I delete this question ?